# Do Soulbolts with ability Emulate Range Weapon need to reload the emulated weapon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

Do Soulbolts with ability Emulate Range Weapon need to reload the emulated weapon?

> **Emulate Ranged Weapon**
>
> The soulknife can form her mind bolt to replicate any single ranged weapon (except firearms), chosen at the time she takes this blade skill. The soulknife is proficient with her mind bolt in this form and it functions in all ways as the chosen weapon. This blade skill may be taken multiple times; each time, it allows the soulknife to form her mind bolt to replicate a different ranged weapon (except firearms). The soulknife must have the ability to form a mind bolt to select this blade skill.

Does this also mean that I may have to take feats like Rapid Reload and the like
to keep up the fight?

Comment: You have asked over a dozen questions about Pathfinder psionics while neglecting to add the [[tag:psionics]] tag, or really *any* relevant tag beyond [[tag:pathfinder]] itself. Over a dozen times, this has been fixed for you by other users. And many of those times, you have been told tag your questions correctly. Continuing to ignore the site’s rules and force others to clean up your mess is rude and disrespectful. You aren’t a new user anymore. You have no excuse for not knowing how this works. Fix your question, and stop posting questions without the tags they obviously need.

Comment: (It'd also be useful for those who want to help you if you could in your question link directly to the soulbolt and the page on blade skills… and, in the future, other relevant rules items.)

Comment: Yes, thank you for adding [[tag:psionics]]—but as noted, the issue isn’t psionics specifically, it’s the failure to add the relevant tags to your question. You seem to be doing the bare minimum necessary to get your question answered, and that’s just not how this works. You want people to put care and consideration into the answers to your question, you need to put care and consideration into the question itself. It’s not necessarily obvious what tags exist, but you have a body of questions you can look to for examples. There is at least one more your question should have.

Answer (score 2):

## Strictly speaking, this isn't an issue for this character

Dreamscarred Press's [soulknife](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/) archetype [soulbolt](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/archetypes/dreamscarred-press/soulbolt/) has a different repertoire of [blade skills](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/blade-skills/) than the typical soulknife. Among those available to a typical soulknife and unavailable to the soulbolt is the blade skill **emulate ranged weapon**. Thus a typical soulbolt never need worry about this.

### For a traditional soulknife, it's like the real thing

*This* GM *would* require a soulknife that uses the blade skill emulate ranged weapon to emulate a projectile weapon to provide ammunition for that projectile weapon because the emulated ranged weapon "functions in all ways as the chosen weapon," and projectile weapons need ammunition. Further, because the emulated weapon "functions in all ways as the chosen weapon," a soulknife that's wielding a typical emulated light crossbow, for example, must take a move action that provokes attacks of opportunity to reload that emulated weapon before the emulated weapon can be fired again.

However, this GM *also* assumes that's precisely *why* the soulknife picked that blade skill: so that the soulknife can *both* employ the wide variety of ammunition available to the emulated ranged weapons *and* apply the feats the soulknife possesses that affect that ranged weapon to the emulated range weapon.

(A [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder_RPG/comments/2zpazr/soulknife_blade_skills_emulate_meleeranged_weapon/), a [Giant in the Playground forum thread](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-369960-p-2.html), [Paizo messageboard thread](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2sfda&page=last?Dreamscarred-Press-Psionics-Augmented-Soulknife), and a [Dreamscarred Press forum thread](http://dreamscarred.com/topic/soulbolt-lots-of-questions/) have raised issues about the blade skill emulate ranged weapons, but none of those threads address these issues head on.)

Comment: What GM are you talking about when you say "*This* GM"?

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy  Me. That is, me in my capacity as a GM rather than as a player of the game or a reader of the game. (Thus permitting another GM to make a different ruling.)